# Why my angular material is behind my sidebar?

Tags: css

```
<style>
.autocomplete-custom-template .md-autocomplete-suggestion {
  height: auto;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  white-space: normal;
}
.autocomplete-custom-template .md-autocomplete-suggestion:last-child {
  border-bottom-width: 0;
}
.autocomplete-custom-template .item-title,
.autocomplete-custom-template .item-metadata {
  display: block;
  line-height: 1;
  border : none ;
}
.autocomplete-custom-template .item-title{
    font-size : 14px ;
    margin-bottom : 5px ;
}    
.autocomplete-custom-template a, .autocomplete-custom-template a:hover, .autocomplete-custom-template a:visited, .autocomplete-custom-template a:focus, .autocomplete-custom-template a:active  {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.autocomplete-custom-template a:hover{
    text-decoration : underline;
    text-decoration-color : #337ab7 ;
}

md-content.md-default-theme, md-content{
    background : none ;
}
</style>
<div ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
    <md-content layout-padding="" layout="column">
        <form>
            <md-autocomplete md-dropdown-items="6" md-clear-button="false" id="custom-template"md-menu-class="autocomplete-custom-template"
              md-menu-container-class="custom-container"placeholder="Recherche" md-selected-item="selectedItem" md-search-text="searchText" md-items="item in query(searchText)">
              <md-item-template>
                  <a href="{{item.url}}">t
                  </a>
              </md-item-template>
            </md-autocomplete>
        </form>
    </md-content>
</div>
```

I have autocomplete material element in my project. U can see my css and my html for the element. But I have a problem the list is behind my sidebar.
Even if I try to do `z-index` or `position : absolute` on `.custom-container` I still have this problem. Someone have any idea to resolve my issue ?

[image: menu]

Comment: It looks like a wrong z-index. Please create working fiddle where we can touch the problem, check other styles, etc.

Comment: @pavel I can't make it works on fiddle

Comment: So... good luck. I can't debug your code from image, 99% you're looking z-index.

Comment: @pavel when i put z-index `.autocomplete-custom-template` it doesn't work even if I put in all my element